# Object has no attribute - Pyramid

Tags: python, pyramid

I have mail.py file:

```
# coding: utf-8

from ..lib.common import *
from ..lib.common import _
from ..lib.forms import *


import os

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class mail(BaseHandler):

   @view_config(route_name="mail", renderer="mail/mail.mako")
   def index(self):
      return {
        'mail':mail
      }


   @view_config(route_name="send")
   def send(request):
      data = request.params['in']
      return Response(str(data))
```

and mail.maco:

```
   ## coding: utf-8                                                                                                                        
   <%inherit file="../base.mako" />

   <form action="${request.route_url('send')}" method="post">

   <input type="text" name="in"  size="50">
   <input type="submit" value="SEND" >

   </form>
```

I want to get 'in''s text. But when i press send button pyramid show me error:

```
AttributeError: 'mail' object has no attribute 'params'
```

If i write

```
Response('some text')
```

everything works great and text shows, but i want to get input text. Why do I get this error?

[image: error]

Comment: Please fix your indentation and provide the full traceback of your error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `send()` method is lacking the `self` parameter.  (At least I'm guessing it is supposed to be a method.  Since the indentation of your post is wrong, I can't tell.)

Comment: Do you mean i have to append that code:                                       @view_config(route_name="send")
    def send(self):
        return dict()

Comment: presumably `def send(self): data = self.request.params['in']`